# Wrapping initialized arrays into another array with swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am trying to wrap some initialized arrays into another array. I am getting my error when I try to wrap all the chapters

ERROR:
"cannot use instance member 'chapter1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

I tried looking all over stack overflow and couldn't find anything.

```
class QuestionBankDatabase {

    //MARK: - Singleton to access the array information
    static let shared = QuestionBankDatabase()

    //MARK: - Chapter properties

    var chapter1 = [Question]()
    var chapter2 = [Question]()
    var chapter3 = [Question]()
    var chapter4 = [Question]()
    var chapter5 = [Question]()
    var chapter6 = [Question]()
    var chapter7 = [Question]()
    var chapter8 = [Question]()
    var chapter9 = [Question]()
    var chapter10 = [Question]()
    var chapter11 = [Question]()
    var chapter12 = [Question]()
    var chapter13 = [Question]()
    var chapter14 = [Question]()
    var chapter15 = [Question]()
    var chapter16 = [Question]()
    var chapter17 = [Question]()
    var chapter18 = [Question]()
    var chapter19 = [Question]()
    var chapter20 = [Question]()
    var chapter21 = [Question]()

    //This is Source Of Truth
    var allChapters = [chapter1, chapter2, chapter3, chapter4, chapter5, chapter6, chapter7, chapter8, chapter9, chapter10, chapter11, chapter12, chapter13, chapter14, chapter15, chapter16, chapter17, chapter18, chapter19, chapter20, chapter21]

...

//MARK: - Chapter 1
//Chapter 1: Question 2

let allQuestions = Question(question: "High-ranking Egyptians shaved their heads ____.", possibleAnswers: ["to provide a job", "for aesthetic reasons", "to prevent infestations of parasites", "for religious reasons"], correctAnswer: "to prevent infestations of parasites", explanation: "High-ranking men and women of Egypt shaved their heads to prevent infestations of parasites. They also did this for increased comfort when wearing wigs.")

        //Append Method
        chapter1.append(allQuestions)

        //Chapter 1: Question 2
        chapter1.append(Question(question: "Meryma’at was a famous Egyptian barber who practiced his skills ____ years ago.", possibleAnswers: ["500", "2,000", "4,000", "6,000"], correctAnswer: "6,000", explanation: "Meryma’at was a famous Egyptian barber who practiced his skills 6,000 years ago. His work was held in such high esteem that his image was sculpted for posterity."))
...
```

And so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to access your properties before `init`.
To solve that, make your `allChapters` variable **lazy**, so it gains its value only when it's being accessed.

e.g.
`lazy var allChapters = [chapter1, ...]`

Comment: you sir are simply a God amounts men

Answer (score 0):

What you’re doing is a simple mistake. Instead of doing `var chapter1 = [Question]()`, use `var chapter1 : [Question] = []`. This creates an empty `Question` array. Then, add questions to the chapters using append as you already have been. Best of luck with your project!